# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "Salman" not found;

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have tried to run the following test in my spring application.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=App1Application.class)
@Sql(scripts="customerTest.sql")
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)

public class customerTest {


    @Autowired 
    customerRepository  customerDB;

    @Test
    public void countRecords(){

        assertThat(customerDB.count(),is(2l));

    }   
}
```

and in the **customerTest.sql** file i have:

```
insert into customer(id,name,lastname) values(1,"name","lastname");
```

here is my **customer** class

```
@Entity
@Data

public class customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;

    String name;
    String lastname;
    }
```

and i use **jpa** too:

```
public interface customerRepository  extends JpaRepository<customer,Long>{

}
```

The problem is, when i run the test i face with the error:

```
 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "Salman" not found; SQL statement:
insert into customer(id,name,lastname) values(1,"name","lastname")
```

Meanwhile "Salman" is a value and not a column?

Please pay attention, i am using spring-mvc so there is **no Database**
I have only my models (`customer`) made by code.

Comment: So what does the file "customerTest.sql" contain?

Comment: it contains 2 insert queries, as i mentioned

Comment: Double-quote `"` is a reserved character in SQL.  Therefore, `"Salman"` is not a string value as you expect but an object identifier, which in the context of the `INSERT` statement is inferred to be a column name.  Strings in SQL need to be wrapped in single-quotes `'`.  `"Salman"` should be `'Salman'` and `"Lashkarara"` should be `'Lashkarara'`.

Comment: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#string

Comment: The first three letters of "last" and the first three letters of "name" concatenated, perhaps?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The behavior of compiler to make such an error is still a question for me,
but I managed to handle this error using this single quote `''` rather than double quote `""`

I use this

```
insert into customer(id,name,lastname) values(1,'name','Lastname')
```

rather than

```
 insert into customer(id,name,lastname) values(1,"name","Lastname")
```

Comment: Spent hours before I finally found this answer. Worked like charm. But I never thought " would create problem. What's going on here?

Comment: Saviour for me, spent hours. Any specific reason why is it so and if there is a fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use '' (single quotes) instead of "" (double quotes). I think it's a problem in H2 library

Answer (score 0):

I know this is bit late for this answer but it still needs an improvement.
Do not pass or insert values like this in database, there is always a chances of SQL injection. What you can do is you can use `PreparedStatement` and then pass a value to your query by using `setString()` or `setInteger()` or what ever value you want to pass. So your query will have a better performance and also the security threats are minimum. For e.g.,

```
String insert = "INSERT into table_name(id, name,lastname) values (?, ?, ?)"
PreparedStatement insertStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
insertStatement.setInteger(1, id);
insertStatement.setString(2, name);
insertStatement.setString(3, lastname);
insertStatement.executeUpdate();
insertStatement.close();
```

where `conn` is the connection made to your database. And do not forget to close the `PreparedStatement` and connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use FULL PATH to your database in project. This problem was solved after relative path was excluded. There is some bug with "~/RELATIVE_PATH" using in last H2 database versions!
Bad example:
"jdbc:h2:~\com\project\db\h2\h2testdb"
GOOD EXAMPLE:
"jdbc:h2:C:\Users\UserName\IdeaProjects\projectname\com.project\src\main\java\com\test\db\h2\h2testdb"

Answer (score 0):

You must set the name of the database table field in the entity module (in your case `customer.java` class) as follows:

```
@Column(name = "field_name_in_the_table")
String name;
```

Then in your SQL script file `customerTest.sql` write the database filed name as follows:

```
INSERT INTO customer (id, field_name_in_the_table, lastname) values(1,"name","lastname");
```